# Bootstrap: button not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

**Bootstrap buttons not working properly**

Buttons next and prev, switch on home-page instead of different slide.
I did it 10 times from 0, definitely I do something wrong.

**This is my code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Numele Site-ului</a>
    </div>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchAdvert">
        </div>
      </form>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators dot nav-->

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- wrapper for slides -->

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/audi.jpg" alt="audi">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Amazing RS7</h1>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/bmw.jpg" alt="bmw">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Awesome Bmw X6</h1>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/mercedes.jpg" alt="mercedes">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>This is ME.</h1>
      </div>  
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- controls or next and prev btns-->

    <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: this is image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking and what the problem is.

Comment: when i click on next or prev button, is changing to another page(.html), not on the next slide(image).

Comment: Sort that out, instead of href="#myCarousel", inside buttons code, i change to data-target="#myCarousel".